# Interrupted Internet browsing on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, internet, browsing

**My question**: Can Windows 7 (not original version) create trouble in Internet browsing in few cases?

**My Fact**: Since few weeks, I have not been getting good Internet connection while I browse Internet on Chrome or Firefox, or while I use FTP using FileZilla, though I use multiple Internet services. I never faced this problem in file downloading. My Internet connections are 1 Mbps wireless connection and alternative EDGE modem with low bandwidth.

A support person of the Wireless Internet provider suggests me to re-install my Windows 7 OS. According to his opinion, the Internet problem is occurred, because the OS is not original and installed one and half year ago. May it be true cause?

Please note that ping test (ping facebook.com -t) also gets few data loss sometimes.

I am asking this question here to get idea regarding the possible underlying causes for this current problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "not the original version" do you mean Windows 7 Service Pack 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe your windows has some issue in registry and/or driver or you have issue with antivirus , but using non original version of windows has no effect on internet browsing capabilit

1. check your antivirus software and check you have latest update.
2. Check for any WiFi Driver update.
3. Reset your windows Firewall to it's default settings or disable it and test your internet speed as below:
   [image]
4. Cleanup your registry with tools such as [CCleaner](http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner)

Comment: A corrupted registry isn't going to effect the strength of his signal connection to his wireless internet.  I also doubt this is a driver issue since there is packet lose, this indicates there is a problem, with the connection itself to the service provider.

Comment: Thanks for answer and comments. I've done steps 1 and 2. I'll apply stop 3 & 4 when necessary. As Internet problem is occurred frequently (but not all time), it may be fault of Internet service provider. Are you both answering that non original version of windows has no effect on internet browsing capability? If it has no effect, the service provider give me wrong support, doesn't?

Comment: @Ramhound something like Max TCP/IP concurrent connections, MTU has many settings in Registry that can cause this issue.

Comment: I'm sure about your non original version of windows because I'm happy with that kind of windows 7 for long time. :D

Comment: I would be bit concerned whether registry cleaner tool is safe or not? Though CCleaner is one of the best according to expert opinion.

Comment: it's automatically backup registry, so you can use it without any issue